# PHP, Newsletter Template

Tags: php, phpmailer, newsletter

I'm sending newslleter with PHP + PHPMailer. Actually i wrote this code:

```
$message = file_get_contents('templates/gallery.php');
// Replace the % with the actual information 
$message = str_replace('%username%', $username, $message); 

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->AddAddress('miblint@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Your account information';
$mail->Body = $message;
!$mail->Send();
```

But now, i need to send deals in the newsletter. Is there another way to append the content to the template, through a loop deals?

Comment: Can't you just edit gallery.php? I don't understand the question.

Comment: I would imagine it would go something like `$message .= 'Deals!';`, just after replacing the username. What are these deals and where do they come from? Is this in the same e-mail or a separate one?

Comment: Yes i can edit gallery.php, but i need to put inside them content from database..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template system like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or another to parse the content. Then put the content to your mail.